# Data dump of Hibernate-based application

Tags: database, hibernate, serialization, dump

Is there some tool for do dump data to some format. May be XML, JSON, CSV etc for using it in other application(may be with other DB engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) for that, it can dump datasets in XML, CSV.